# How to solve the proportion $3n(n-5) = n-6(3n+1)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Solve: $$3n(n-5) = n-6(3n+1)$$

I can distribute the $3n(1n-5)$, but I don't know how to distribute the $1n-6(3n + 1)$

Comment: First make sure you get the brackets right.  Your problem should be $$(n-6)/(3n)=(n-5)/(3n+1)\ ,$$ at least I assume this is what you mean, and your first step should be $$(3n)(n-5)=(n-6)(3n+1)\ .$$ If you are sloppy in this respect you are going to get very confused and make lots of errors.

Comment: What do you mean by distribute? And what is $1n$? Do you mean $n$?

Comment: All these people worrying on how the format is... but not helping me lol.  My question is, how do you distribute n-6(3n+1)

Comment: They are commenting that your question does not make sense. It is like asking someone "What is squirrel downspout?" It is missing keywords to help us know what the question really is.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean $n - 6(3n+1)$ then you distribute as $n-6\cdot 3n - 6= n-18n - 6 = -17n - 6$.

If you mean $(n-6)(3n+1)$, then you do the first two things multiplied together ($n \cdot 3n$), added to the outer terms multiplied together ($n\cdot 1$) added to the inner things multiplied together ($-6 \cdot 3n$) added to the last terms multiplied together ($-6 \cdot 1$)

All told we have $$(n-6)(3n+1) = n\cdot 3n+ n\cdot 1+-6 \cdot 3n+ -6 \cdot 1 = 3n^2 -17n-6$$

Neither of these equal $3n(n-5)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $$(a+b)(c+d)=ac+ad+bc+bd$$